# Accessing the API properly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

I have a simple project with Laravel 6 in which I AJAX load data from my Blade view. So I could have :

```
$.ajax({url: "api/users", success: (result) => { ...
```

This example involves two routes :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('api/users', 'Api\ApiUsersController@index');
Route::middleware('auth:web')->get('users', 'UsersController@users');
```

I would like to understand how to properly fetch the API data from the `users` page.

1. If I manually do `$.ajax({url: "api/users?api_token={{Auth::user()->api_token}}"` then this token can be easily stolen and the authentication can be bypassed.
2. If I change my API middleware in `auth:web`, then nobody could access the API with real applications API Tokens.

I guess the best way would be to save the default user API token in the session and fetch it if it exists  from the api guard.

What is the proper way to proceed?

Comment: Have you considered using [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport)? It includes abiltiies to consume the API with Javascript quite easily.

It is worth noting that ideally, in your example case, having the token on display shouldn't really matter. The "worst case scenario" _should_ be that they do whatever it is that you're already allowing them to do via the user interface, via API methods instead. Same result, different methods.

Comment: @CmdrSharp Passport seems to be cumbersome for what I need. I already have a kind of OAuth2 authentication in place and I do not want to get more complexity in my app.

Comment: @nowox if, as you say, you already have a kind of OAuth2, what stops you from sending the token provided by it, which is save to store on the client and pass to the API? In this case your OAuth2 token will be the kind of session cookie that can be used to authenticate each user request at every call, though it's best to pass it in the headers, not URI. And, as you have been advised by CmdrSharp, it might be better off to switch to official solution and avoid any further complexities down the way.